# How to hide angular element on click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a situation somewhat like this below code. I have a delete button on view cart page when it is pressed an API is called to delete the product and I just hide the product div tag to avoid page reload initially. How to hide multiple products one by one

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hide = function(){
  //WHAT SHOULD GO HERE
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

<h5 ng-click="hide()" ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">{{x}}<!-- HOW TO USE ng-hide HERE --></h5>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular Way of: show or hide element after button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318924/angular-way-of-show-or-hide-element-after-button-click)

Comment: On delete click you can remove the item from array then it will not show in the repeater

Comment: Dear @lin I dont consider this basic ng-hide ng-show question. Its about hiding multiple values with same ng-model. Regards

Comment: Yea, there are tons of questions with tons of answers to your problem. No need to ask it again.

Comment: @AravindSivam I am considering your answer let me try

Comment: As you can see, this question is a nub catcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have following in your HTML:

```
<h5 ng-hide="hide{{$index}}" ng-click="hide($index)" 
    ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">{{x}}</h5>
```

Now, your `hide()` function would look like this,

```
$scope.hide = function(index){
  $scope['hide'+index] = true
}
```

That should hide numbers on click.

Here's working example!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hide = function(index){
    $scope['hide'+index] = true
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

<h5 ng-hide="hide{{$index}}" ng-click="hide($index)" ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">{{x}}<!-- HOW TO USE ng-hide HERE --></h5>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the product div tag to **avoid page reload initially**

just get type button without type="submit" ( inside `<form></form>` )

**`<button type="submit" >` to >>> `<button ng-click="hide()">`**

Answer (score 0):

Update your COntroller like that :

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
          $scope.hide = function(x){
          //WHAT SHOULD GO HERE
    $scope.list.splice(x, 1);
          }
        });







 <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

    <h5 ng-click="hide($index)" ng-repeat="x in list">{{x}}</h5>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-hide is just css(display:none) way hide element. ng-if is add/remove DOM element. (we can see if u hide element, ng-if we can't see).

You try remove. Just see the example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
  $scope.hide = function(index){  
  // in api call success function  
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >

<h5 ng-click="hide($index)" ng-repeat="x in data">{{x}}<!-- HOW TO USE ng-hide HERE --></h5>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```